# Return list of all non standard nodes (duplicate) from xml column in sql database

Tags: sql, xml

Can you help?

I have a table 'ED' with columns NAME and XMLOUTPUT

Example of the table is

```
Name              XMLOUTPUT
Person1           Snippet below
```

XMLOUTPUT is

```
<Fields>
        <f Name="FIRSTNAME" ColumnOrder="0" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
        <f Name="KEYNAME" ColumnOrder="1" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
        <f Name="AGE" ColumnOrder="2" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
        <f Name="BIRTHDATE" ColumnOrder="3" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
        <f Name="LOOKUPID" ColumnOrder="4" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
        <f Name="MIDDLENAME" ColumnOrder="5" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
        <f Name="Blue (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
          <f Name="Red (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
          <f Name="Yellow (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
          <f Name="Green (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
            <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
            <ParentView/>
        </f>
    </Fields>
```

What Im trying to do is select the Name column in ED table as well as any Names from the XMLOUTPUT that have (color)

Ideally the output would be

```
NAME          XMLOUTPUT
Person1       Blue (color)
Person1       Red (color)
Person 1      Yellow (color)
Person1       Green (color)
```

the closest I have come so far is

```
select NAME as EDNAME,

    CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),  XMLOUTPUT), '', ''), '', '')
    AS xml).value('(//*:f/@Name) [1] ', 'varchar(50)')
    as Color
    
    from ED
    
    where NAME = 'Person 1'
```

But this does retrieve but only retrieves the 1st  due to the [1] in the statement.
Im looking for something that will pull all values where @Name like '%color%'

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try  the following solution.

The XPath XQuery `contains()` function is very handy for your scenario.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Name] VARCHAR(20), XMLOUTPUT XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([Name], XMLOUTPUT) VALUES
('Person1', N'<Fields>
    <f Name="FIRSTNAME" ColumnOrder="0" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="KEYNAME" ColumnOrder="1" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="AGE" ColumnOrder="2" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="BIRTHDATE" ColumnOrder="3" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="LOOKUPID" ColumnOrder="4" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="MIDDLENAME" ColumnOrder="5" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="Blue (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="Red (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="Yellow (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
    <f Name="Green (color)" ColumnOrder="6" SortSequence="-1">
        <FieldWasFlattened>false</FieldWasFlattened>
        <ParentView/>
    </f>
</Fields>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, [Name]
    ,c.value('@Name', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS Result
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY XMLOUTPUT.nodes('/Fields/f[contains(@Name, "(color)")]') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| ID |  Name   |     Result     |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 | Person1 | Blue (color)   |
|  1 | Person1 | Red (color)    |
|  1 | Person1 | Yellow (color) |
|  1 | Person1 | Green (color)  |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much Yitzhak , I couldnt get the solution working with the contains criteria , it would output all of the rows if I omitted it....- I lazily just stuck it in a select with swapping out your cross apply line for CROSS APPLY XMLOUTPUT.nodes('//*:f') AS t(c))

Comment: @davie, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.