# Navigating nodes for select in XML (Crossapply,XMLnamespaces) SQL

Tags: sql, xml, cross-apply, tns

I have a query that will bring me back correct nodes from XML.
However when I try to change the criteria I get no results

I know Im probably just referencing the wrong nodes but this is a one off and I have no real experience in XML/nodes and got the script online and changed minimally for it to work.

Can you help?

I an get the TAB values OK but when I try to change the TNS: for section nodes it returns no results - I just need the section caption and ID.

XML:

```
 </Tab>
<Tab Caption="Works" ID="7f789fee-1aa4-4341-801a-f31d1daf1bcc" 
  <Tabs>
    <Tab Caption="Works" ID="24e52dcf-fb35-4a29-8890-9eec6bde28c2" 
      <Sections>
        <Section ID="631e1555-89fa-4306-801f-6a1d7b23a435" Caption="ThisOne" 
        </Section>
      </Sections>
    </Tab>
```

Script

```
    with xmlnamespaces ('Page' as tns, 'commontypes' as common)

select 
    page.section.value('@ID', 'uniqueidentifier') as ID_GUID,
    page.section.value('@Caption', 'nvarchar(max)') as Section
from dbo.PAGELIBRARY as P
  cross apply P.PAGELIBRARYXML.nodes('tns:Page/tns:Sections/tns:Section') as page(section) 
where  P.ID = '88159265-2b7e-4c7b-82a2-119d01ecd40f'
```

I can retrieve the TAB info OK using

```
 cross apply P.PAGELIBRARYXML.nodes('tns:Page/tns:Tabs/tns:Tab') as page(tab)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Hey - I have the code working OK - I just need to point it to a different node in the XML and my attempts have failed obviously because I dont know what Im doing. Im not asking for creation of code - just how to  "switch" to another node in the XML provided - thanks for looking

Comment: We don't have your environment, and we need to re-create it via a minimal reproducible example, ##1-4. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Your XML sample is not a well-formed XML, and doesn't have any namespaces. Though your code is using namespaces...

Comment: I already helped you in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100717/return-list-of-all-non-standard-nodes-duplicate-from-xml-column-in-sql-databas Just check the answer, and how it follows the same **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, and it is working.

Comment: You are right and I am sorry I could only give the basics (sensitive data) and again thank you for helping me - I learned to get it to work I had to work down the child nodes using tns: on each node I drilled into - really common sense but today I have none .This got me over the line. P.PAGEDEFINITIONSPEC.nodes('tns:PageDefinitionSpec/tns:Tabs/tns:Tab/tns:Sections/tns:Section')   -thanks again Yitzhak.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the below example allowed me to navigate through the xml element nodes - tns:root/tns:/firstNode/tns:/childnode etc etc

```
P.PAGEDEFINITIONSPEC.nodes('tns:PageDefinitionSpec/tns:Tabs/tns:Tab/tns:Sections/tns:Section')
```

Thanks to Yitzhak Khabinsky for guidance